# Working code vs. working program

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, scope, help-center, broken-code

I have a feeling that our guidances should be worded better. Take this excerpt from the Help Center:

> To the best of my knowledge, does the code work?

I believe this question is *incorrect*, as seen by https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/75043/c-youtube-downloader-error and there are most likely more questions around.

We should be asking people if, to the best of their knowledge, they think that their **program** works, not their code. We can see cases where people post code here that does compile and does not throw exceptions during runtime, yet does not do what is intended. So they conclude that their code works, but their program does not. We, as a general consensus, however require that their program works.

---

Hence my suggestion is to replace all occurrences of "does the code work" to "does the program work", wherever it makes sense. The obvious replacement would be in the Help Center in the excerpt listed above, perhaps there are more places where it should be changed.

This will not get rid of off-topic questions from users that do not read anything, but it will discourage users who know what they are doing and truly believe posting here is correct, because their code works in spite of their program not working.

Comment: I've  added "… as intended" to the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This site being **Code** Review, we require working **code**.  We review excerpts of code that aren't complete programs.  They could be library functions or even just a line or two of code.

Let's not change our wording from "code" to "program" just because some users have an excessively liberal concept of what "working" means.

Comment: "the code is working, it just doesn't do what I want that it does!", is that a very liberal concept?

Comment: I'd be OK with adding "To the best of my knowledge, does the code work **as intended**?"

Comment: +1 for "works as intended".

Comment: Yes yes. Works as intended.